# Algebraic closure not even finitely generated over base field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, splitting-field

> Show the algebraic closure $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$  is not even finitely generated over the field $\mathbb{Q}$

I'm not sure how to go about this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Show that for any natural $n$, there is an algebraic extension of $\Bbb Q$ of degree (at least) $n$. And any finitely generated algebraic extension has some finite degree.

Comment: Could I say that since [Q bar : Q] = infinity, after what you suggested, would be a contradiction and thus proving the premise?

Comment: @Christian No contradiction at all. Just proving $[\overline{\Bbb Q}:\Bbb Q]\geq n$ for all $n$. That's all we need.

Comment: Thank you so much!